# Know Which file is open

Tags: python

I'm reading from a folder of txt files, in a loop in this way:

```
path = './input/*.txt'
files=glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
  with open (file, 'rt') as f:
   fstr= f.read()
```

Is there a way to know on which file the program is atm?
I want to print it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the variable name `file`?

Comment: No, I mean the name of the file which is in its path: c://input/123.txt

Comment: print(file) inside the for loop

Comment: That worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[putonspectacles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4356204/putonspectacles) answered it: print(file) inside the loop